# Align a system equation with three separate equations in latex

Tags: equations, align, alignment, alignat

The equations in LaTeX are:

```
 \[\min_{T \geq 0} =\sum_{i,j=1}^n T_{ij}c(i,j) \]
 \[subject \ to: \sum_{j=1}^n T_{ij = d_{i}} \ \forall \ \in i \{1,...,n\} \tag{2.7}\]
 \[\sum_{i=1}^n T_{ij} = d_{j}^{'} \ \forall \ \in j \{1,...,n\} \]
```

And the result is:

[image]

These equations should be in the same alignment based on the sigma symbols.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Please can you put a minimal compilable code of your question? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to do it, with the `aligned` environment. I added another solution with the dedicated package `optidef`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, optidef}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}\label{eq:optim}
  \begin{aligned}
\min_{T \geq 0}\enspace &\smashoperator{ \sum_{i,j=1}^n }T_{ij}c(i,j) \\
\text{subject to: } & \sum_{j=1}^n T_{ij = d_{i}} \ \forall \ i\in \{1,...,n\} \\
& \sum_{i=1}^n T_{ij} = d_{j}^{'} \ \forall \ j\in \{1,...,n\}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{mini}|s|[2]
{\scriptstyle T \geq 0} {\smashoperator{ \sum_{i,j=1}^n} T_{ij}c(i,j)}%
{}{}
\addConstraint{\sum_{j=1}^n T_{ij}= d_{i}}{\quad\forall \ i\in \{1,...,n\} }
\addConstraint{\sum_{i=1}^n T_{ij}= d’_{j}}{\quad\forall \ j\in \{1,...,n\} }
\end{mini}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very very good and I have appreciated much your solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly :)